# I need help with zenity to list files

Tags: command-line, bash, xubuntu, zenity

I have the command

```
sudo find / -size +450M -exec ls -lhGSr {} \;
```

to find and list files greater than 450M. I know how to display the output in zenity, but I'd like to select a path (any) in zenity output, then double click and this path is opened in a File Manager (in my case in Thunar). How can I achieve that?

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS running command: `sudo find / -size +450M -exec ls -lhGSr {} \;**` generates the error message: `find: missing argument to `-exec'` Are you sure the command is accurate?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The command is correct : sudo find / -size +450M -exec ls -lhGSr {} \; THERE ARE NO ** at the end, I don't know who edited my question, these  ** at the beginning and at the end are to make text BOLD.

Comment: What path do you want to select? A path to search with the find command (replacing root in the command in your question) or one of the paths in the output from that command?

Comment: @sudodus the second option : one of the paths in the output from that command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is possible to do that, you should keep in mind that it will waste time looking in directories such as `/sys`, `/proc` and `/dev`, which you should probably leave alone.

That said, this little script does what you asked for:

```
selectedFile=$(sudo find / -size +450M -exec sudo -u "$USER" zenity --list --column "Found files" {} +)
if [ -n "$selectedFile" ]; then
    selectedFileDir=$(dirname "$selectedFile")
    thunar "$selectedFileDir"
fi
```

`find` is executed with privileges, but Zenity is run as your normal user (graphical applications should not be run as root). When the first line finishes you are presented the Zenity dialog. Since you need to provide the directory which contains the selected file as an argument to `thunar`, I extract it with `dirname`.

Comment: That's it, thanks for scripting the expected solution. Thanks all guys.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you create a selection list in `zenity` as in the following example, where the files in the current folder are listed:

```
zenity --list --column="Files" $(ls)
```

This command will display a zenity dialog with the output of the `ls` command. When an item is selected, it is printed to standard out.

You can combine commands such that action is directly taken on the output of `zenity` as following:

```
xdg-open $(zenity --list --column="Files" $(ls))
```

Specifically for XFCE, you may prefer to use `exo-open` instead `xdg-open`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. One more question, when I change ls command to, for example, ls -l ,why it doesn't work? it gives an error.

Comment: It is obvious you cannot feed the command xdg-open with any text. It has to be a valid file or URL.